# @Html.PagedListPager can't be found

Tags: c#, pagedlist, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a ASP.NET.CORE 2.0 application and I want to add paging to my site. I started with Troy Goode PagedList but I got the same error and I went to try the X version and still got the same results.

```
Reference to type 'HtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

I can't even find in intellisense the method `@Html.PagedListPager`
UPDATE: It doesn't work on a brand new empty project

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc; @*import this so we get our HTML Helper*@
@using X.PagedList; 
@model IPagedList<StecajneObjave.Models.ViewModels.ObjavaViewModel>



<p>
     <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
    <table class="table">
   <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatumObjave)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NazivStecajnogDuznika)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OIBStecajnogDuznika)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delaji", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
   </tbody>
  </table>

<h3>Minimal Paging Control w/ Page Count Text</h3>
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

I have tried reinstalling nuget packages, cleaning and rebuilding the solution but nothing seems to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: sounds like that plugin doesn't support MVC Core

Comment: Use X.PagedList and X.PagedList.Mvc.Core 7.5.0 version for .Net core 2.1 framework. Latest version not working in .net core 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have an **extra conversion** over here:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

This is because your model is already an IPagedList:

```
@model IPagedList<StecajneObjave.Models.ViewModels.ObjavaViewModel>
```

So all you have to do in the paged list it:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Second, You are passing Url.Action but **forget a parameter**:

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

When it should be:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Controller","Action", new { page }))
```

**EDIT:**

See the reference for asp .net core 2 HtmlString, it is different then Asp.Net MVC:

[HtmlString documantation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.html.htmlstring?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: Thank you, I pasted the code from the github repository. But I still can't see the PagedListPager method.

Comment: try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517359/pagedlist-core-mvc-pagedlistpager-html-extension-in-net-core-is-not-there

Answer (score 15):

The answers above didn't help me but I found a solution that might also help others.

**Change to this:**

`@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core`

I also had a using statement that was using `@using X.PagedList.Mvc` only. I don't get why the other user got downvoted because it works.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Their GitHub page doesn't have that `Core` part so it threw me off: https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList

Comment: You have saved my day, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and adding @using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core will show it in the intellisense. Hope this help.